# webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch not working if div is too small

Tags: ios, css, touch, overflow

I'm using the `webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` property on an iOS/Android WebApp and it works in most cases and provides a native scrolling experience without Rubberband Scrolling.

Now the issue is, when the div that needs to be scrolled **isn't tall enough** the rubberband scrolling will happen again. I tried setting `height:100%` but that didn't help either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this when I made a Cordova iOS app. You can fix this by applying `min-height: 101%`. Though, that would make your page scrollable for a minor distance but it will trigger the desired effect you're looking for.